# Nginx open() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed

Tags: nginx, dd-wrt

I'm trying to run nginx on a very stripped down linux, and when I try to run it I get

`[emerg] 4905#0: open() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)`

and

`[alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)`

Now, my problem is that `/etc` is on a read-only filesystem, so I can't make that directory, nor can I symlink to it. Everything is installed in `/opt/etc/...` and `nginx -c /opt/mnt/nginx/nginx.conf` also does not work.

How do I make nginx run?

Comment: `nginx` isn't running in a chroot by any chance?

Comment: Whatever the problem was in January, I've since fixed it. I don't remember what the problem was or how I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Since `/etc` is read only you could use something like `aufs` to overlay another directory on it for your changes, effectivly giving you `rw` on /etc. For example:

```
mkdir /myconfig /mnt/etc
mount -t aufs br=/myconfig:/etc /mnt/etc
mount -o bind /mnt/etc /etc
```